# Solutions to $DCD^T\bar{v}=\lambda\bar{v}$ in terms of $C^{-1}$ elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've got the solutions to this eigenvalue equation:

$$DCD^T\bar{v}=\lambda\bar{v}$$

In the problem I'm working at, the elements of $C^{-1}$ make more physical sense than those of $C$. Therefore, I'd like to express the solutions $\lambda_i$ and $\bar{v}_i$ in terms of the elements of $C^{-1}$ (and $D$).

I've tried inverting $C$ directly and "translating" each element by itself, i.e. substituting $C_{i,j}=f_{i,j}((C^{-1})_{i,j})$ in the eigenvalues and -vectors, but the resulting expressions are very complicated. Is there any hope for a better and simpler solution?

I know that $C$ is real, symmetric, positive definite 6x6. $D$ is 3x6 with linearly independent rows.

In my case, the matrices are:

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}&C_{12}&C_{13}&0&0&0\\
C_{12}&C_{11}&C_{13}&0&0&0\\
C_{13}&C_{13}&C_{33}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&C_{44}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&C_{44}&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&C_{66}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\phi&0&0&0&\cos\phi&0\\
0&0&0&\cos\phi&0&\sin\phi\\
0&0&\cos\phi&0&\sin\phi&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Rightarrow DCD^T = \begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}\sin^2\phi + C_{44}\cos^2\phi & 0 & (C_{13}+C_{44})\cos\phi\sin\phi \\
0 & C_{66}\sin^2\phi + C_{44}\cos^2\phi & 0 \\ 
(C_{13}+C_{44})\cos\phi\sin\phi & 0 & C_{44}\sin^2\phi + C_{33}\cos^2\phi
\end{bmatrix}$$

If $D$ were a square matrix I would have tried writing $(DCD^T)^{-1}=(D^T)^{-1}C^{-1}D^{-1}$ and going from there, but unfortunately that isn't the case, and from what I know the above relation doesn't hold under the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.